# How to reuse/include existing java servlets and filters in Clojure + Compojure + Ring Web application?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

I have bunch of Java EE artifacts like the gzip servlet filter, a file upload servlet etc. which are ok and I want to reuse them in my Clojure Web application based on Compojure and Ring.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Ring, on which Compojure sits, produces a servlet which you can then thread with the rest of your servlets in your tomcat config. **Ring+Compujure servlets are peers to your other servlets** and the other servlets will have no need to know that Clojure was involved. The "downside" is that they can only compose at the servlet level which is in my opinion less well than composition of middleware etc. in Ring composes with other middleware and with frameworks such as Compojure.

Comment: So  should I generate an uberwar using lein , 'unjar' the war file, and then in the war file's web.xml, I should add the servlet and filter definitions and contexts etc. and then 'jar' it back to warfile?

Comment: there *must* be a more elegant way of going about this :-/ though that's the idea, yes.